# Is finite verbal subgroup equivalent to finite index of marginal subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory, universal-algebra

There is a well known fact:

> If $G$ is a finitely generated group. Then $|G’| < \infty$ iff $[G:Z(G)]<\infty$.

Suppose $\mathfrak{U}$ is a group variety. Let’s denote the corresponding verbal subgroup as a  $V_{\mathfrak{U}}(G)$ and the corresponding [marginal subgroup](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Marginal_subgroup) as $M_{\mathfrak{U}}(G)$. Note, that for the variety of all abelian groups $\mathfrak{A}$ (defined for the word $[x, y]$) we have $V_{\mathfrak{A}}(G) = G’$ and $M_{\mathfrak{A}}(G) = Z(G)$.

My question is:

Can the aforementioned statement be generalized to the following one:

> Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated group and $\mathfrak{U}$ is a finitely based variety. Then $|V_{\mathfrak{U}}(G)| < \infty$ iff $[G:M_{\mathfrak{U}}(G)]<\infty$.

?

[This question on MSE with several useful comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3444714/407165)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not true. A counterexample was constructed in Ashmanov, I. S.; Olʹshanskiĭ, A. Yu. Abelian and central extensions of aspherical groups. Izv. Vyssh. Uchebn. Zaved. Mat. 1985, no. 11, 48–60, 85. They even contsructed a noetherian group $G$ and a word $v$ with finite verbal subgroup  $v(G)$ and marginal subgroup $v^*(G)$ of infinite index (that answered a question of Ph. Hall).